# Firestore composite query pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

Im trying to paginate a composite index query,

```
let size = data.length
let lastElement = data[size-1].commentCount

db.collection('user-content').orderBy('commentCount','desc').orderBy('likes', 'desc').startAfter(lastElement).limit(10).get()
```

But I'm currently getting this error message

[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Function Query.startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined]

I think it has something to do with startAfter(lastElement)

I have the composite index turned on, and I'm getting data when I first load (without startAfter)

does anyone know how to paginate with composite query ?

Im using Expo SDK41, managed workflow.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are assigning to `data`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using a NUMBER - (`let lastElement = data[size-1].commentCount`) - for `.startAfter(lastElement)` - a little hard to see since you don't show us where `data` is defined, but the NAME `commentCount` does heavily imply it.

`.startAfter()` does NOT expect a number; there doesn't EXIST an index or count that it could use.  `.startAfter()` expects a DOCUMENT SNAPSHOT -

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter

...which is expected to be from a query with the EXACT SAME path(s) and `.where()` clauses (i.e. the same query).  Think of it as "start after this document/snapshot from my PREVIOUS query".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you right that the problem in `lastElement`, which seems `undefined`. You can check it by adding some `console.log`. Better to see reproducible code sample to say more, but general workaround should be like this:

```js
let size = data.length
let lastElement = data[size-1].commentCount || 0 // add a fallback value

db.collection('user-content').orderBy('commentCount','desc').orderBy('likes', 'desc').startAfter(lastElement).limit(10).get()
```